# readline() doesn't read from socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, stream, inet

```
s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(address), port);
Thread.sleep(250);
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());       
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

outToServer.writeBytes("MY_QUERY");

String rs = inFromServer.readLine();

s.close();
```

Nothing happens, but if i use .read() i receive the first character of the string.

I don't know what is the message lenght i'll receive, in python i use: sock.recv(1024) where 1024 is the max lenght i can receive.

Is there any way to do the same thing in java?

Answer (score 0):

According to javadoc of readLine():

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

Make sure that the String has the correct structure.

Comment: At the other end there is listening a php server, that decodes my query and then writes answer:
@socket_write($client, implode(',', $dispositivi) . '\n');

Answer (score 0):

You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. writeBytes() writes exactly what you provide to it, no more, no less, and no new lines.

And you should be either using two streams or a Reader and a Writer, not a mixture of both.

Comment: Please, can you give me an example?
I can't understand why it works with one single character, and for the entire line it doesn't

Comment: Because you aren't writing lines, as I said. You aren't sending a newline character, and `readLine()` blocks until it receives one. Add a `\n` to the end of the string you're sending, or take the hint and use a `BufferedWriter` instead of the `DataOutputStream`, and use `BufferedWriter.write(String)` and then `BufferedWriter.newline()`.

Comment: `BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()) );  
BufferedWriter outToServer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()) );  
outToServer.write("QUERY");       outToServer.newLine();
rs = inFromServer.readLine();  
s.close()
`

there aren't changes...

Comment: Try a `flush()` after calling `newLine().`